# Why does printf not work? in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, printf

I have written a program sending a simple text to server.
And I just print `ftp >` to my terminal. But the program does not print `ftp >` to terminal.

My OS is OS X Mountain Lion. Code snippet below for reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINE 1024
#define PORTNUM 3600
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int sockfd;
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    char* prompt = "ftp> ";
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    socklen_t addrlen;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&serveraddr, 0x00, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family           =   AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr      =   inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    serveraddr.sin_port             =   htons(PORTNUM);

    addrlen = sizeof(serveraddr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr_in*)&serveraddr, addrlen)== -1)
    {
        perror("connect error :");
        return 0;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        //write(STDOUT_FILENO, prompt, strlen(prompt));
        printf("ftp> ");
        read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, MAXLINE);
        if( write(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE) <= 0)
        {
            perror("write error");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding `\n` to your printf statement. Let me know if that helps?

Answer (score 4):

`printf()` uses buffered I/O.  The key is to call `fflush(stdout);` after your `printf()`, which is triggered typically by newlines (`'\n'`) in the format string.

Comment: But write function work well without fflush. I don't understand why function fflush() uses. Can you tell why?

Comment: `write` does NOT use buffered I/O and immediately writes all contents of the buffer to the output socket.